# Writing on an existing mixed numeric and string text file with different field

Tags: matlab, file, text, overwrite

I have a mixed numeric and string text file with different fields divided by [ ]. Some of its content is like:

```
   [JUNCTIONS]
   ;ID                  Elev            Demand          Pattern         
    2                   0               0                                   ;
    9                   0               0                                   ;
    5                   0               11                                  ;
    6                     0             20                                  ;

    [RESERVOIRS]
    ;ID                 Head            Pattern         
     1                  5                                   ;
     4                  50                                  ;


     [PIPES]
     ;ID         Node1      Node2   Length  Diameter   Roughness   MinorLoss  Status
     66           2         9       1000        250         100         0           Open    ;
     2            9           4         1000      150       100         0        Open   ;
     3            9     5         1000      150       100         0        Open     ;
     4            2         6         1000      150       100         0        Open     ;
```

I want to overwrite numeric variables below the columns "Demand" and "Roughness"  from MATLAB.
Would you please help me. I read about the performance of import and export commands of Matlab, but I couldn't find the solution.

Comment: If you are editing, make sure to get the data vertically aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small script that will read all your data into a cell array. Each cell is a column of data. As Divakar said, make your data is vertically aligned or textscan will stop when one of the lines is not the same as the last.

```
fid = fopen(file,'r');

while 1
    line=fgetl(fid);
    if ~strcmp(line,'')
        if ~isempty(strfind(line,'['))
            % //Let's check it
            start = strfind(line,'[');
            split = strfind(line,']');
            category = line(start+1:split-1);
            if strcmp(category,'PIPES')
                break;
            end
        end
    end
end
% //skip the header line
line=fgetl(fid);
% //So now we're on the right line, let's read in the table.
data = textscan(fid,'%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %s');

fclose(fid);
```